# using for loop in python to convert two strings into one string

Tags: python

For example:

> mangle('hello','people')->'hpeelolpole'

It is meant to combine these two strings, character by character.
This is my function:

```
def mangle(s1,s2):
  s1=list(s1)
  s2=list(s2)
  a=" "
  for i in range(0,min(len(s1),len(s2))):        
    for c in s1:
      for d in s2:
        a=a+c+d
        if len(s1)>len(s2):
          return a+''.join(s1)[min(len(s1),len(s2)): ]
         elif len(s1)<len(s2):
           return a+''.join(s2)[min(len(s1),len(s2)): ]
         else:
           return a
```

but it produces:

```
hphehohphlhee
```

I know the problem is:

```
for c in s1:
　for d in s2:
　　a=a+c+d
```

but I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. You don't need to iterate on both strings. You can simply do it like this:

```
def mangle(s1, s2):
    a = ""
    for i in range(min(len(s1), len(s2))):
        a += s1[i] + s2[i]
    if len(s1) > len(s2):
        return a + s1[min(len(s1), len(s2)):]
    elif len(s1) < len(s2):
        return a + s2[min(len(s1), len(s2)):]
    return a

assert(mangle('hello','people') == "hpeelolpole")
```

This program can be written with [`itertools.izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) like this:

```
try:
    from itertools import izip_longest as zip  # Python 2
except ImportError:
    from itertools import zip_longest as zip   # Python 3

def mangle(s1, s2):
    return "".join(c1 + c2 for c1, c2 in zip(s1, s2, fillvalue=''))

assert(mangle('hello','people') == "hpeelolpole")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools as IT
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    """
    roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C
    http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes (George Sakkis)
    """
    pending = len(iterables)
    nexts = IT.cycle(iter(it).next for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for n in nexts:
                yield n()
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = IT.cycle(IT.islice(nexts, pending))

print(''.join(roundrobin('hello','people')))
```

yields

```
hpeelolpole
```

Comment: that seems like massive overkill. `''.join(chain(*zip('hello','people')))`

Comment: @roippi: `''.join(chain(*zip('hello','people')))` gives an incomplete result: `'hpeelolpol'`

Comment: That is why we should use `izip_longest`/`zip_longest` like in my answer :)

Comment: Didn't see the extra `e` on the end.  Then yeah, `zip_longest` works.

Comment: I like `roundrobin` because it solves the generalized problem. `IT.chain(*IT.izip_longest(*iterables, fillvalue=''))` does not quite solve the problem, (1) because you need to select the right `fillvalue` on a per-problem basis (what if the iterables were not strings?), and (2) because you may not want fillvalues at all.

Comment: I don't look upon roundrobin as overkill because once it is grokked and stored in a module of utility functions, there is zero amortized cost to using it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the strings and grab the characters from the same index.

```
def mangle(s1,s2):
    a=""
    small = min(len(s1),len(s2))
    for i in range(0,small):        
        a = a + s1[i] + s2[i]
    if small is len(s1):
        a = a + ''.join(s2[i+1:])
    else:
        a = a + ''.join(s1[i+1:])
    return a
```